# MMCLI on BusyBox returns "Cannot request manual scan of devices: unsupported' - IMEI

Tags: linux, usb, busybox

I have a USB modem plugged into a BusyBox v1.23.2 appliance. Typically I would be able to get the IMEI number using the **MMCLI** command set. However when this specific card (multiple of the same card - so this specific model) is used I get the output below.

```
edge:~# mmcli -L

No modems were found

edge:~# mmcli -S
    error: couldn't request to scan devices: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Unsupported: Cannot request manual scan of devices: unsupported'
```

The device is on the appliance and working as expected. Is there another command set that can be used to grab the IMEI of the USB 4G Modem?

```
edge:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0424:2240 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get any information from `mmcli` or any other tool.  The issue is within your device firmware.  It is not exposing the information. The usb dongle does not listen to any AT commands.

You could see the details for yourself: `lsusb -v -d 19d2:1405`.

For more information you can check the similar ticket [mmcli is not detecting my 4G dongle, ZTE device](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92345)

Comment: Not the answer I wanted but appears accurate :(

Comment: @PatrickHelms that such are the ZTE devices.  I recommend getting something more opened.